# Material-UI: the key `checked` provided to the classes property is not valid for Switch

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am overriding the Switch Class, as mentioned in the following url:
https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/

```
    <Switch
      checked={this.state.checkedF}
      onChange={this.handleChange('checkedF')}
      value="checkedF"
      classes={{
        checked: classes.checked,
        bar: classes.bar,
      }}
    />
```

However, I get the following error:

> the key `checked` provided to the classes property is not valid for
>   Switch.

I am using the following Libraries:

```
"material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.41",
"material-ui-icons": "1.0.0-beta.17"
```

Why is it not working, even though I am using the same version mentioned in the link.

Comment: Can you please share the file which contains above Switch component?

Answer (score -1):

Be careful with listen functions and js normal functions. Listen functions need to `bind` in React, or just with `MY_FUNCTION = () => {}` . And don't forgot to import `Switch` with `import Switch from 'material-ui/Switch'`

```
import React from 'react';
import Switch from 'material-ui/Switch';

class Switches extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: true,
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch
          checked={this.state.checkedA}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedA')}
          value="checkedA"
        />
        <Switch
          checked={this.state.checkedB}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedB')}
          value="checkedB"
          color="primary"
        />
        <Switch value="checkedC" />
        <Switch disabled value="checkedD" />
        <Switch disabled checked value="checkedE" />
        <Switch defaultChecked value="checkedF" color="default" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Switches;
```

See section Switch : https://material-ui-next.com/demos/selection-controls/